adb sideload factory mode file ends up in error
On Pixel 8a, I was trying to downgrade from Android 15 to Android 14. So, I downloaded  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/akita-ap2a.240905.003.a1-factory-39b3cda7.zip which is the last factory release of Android 14.
However, adb sideload the above zip ends up in an error. It says:
ERROR: recovery: footer is wrong
ERROR: recovery: Signature verification faield
ERROR: recovery: error 21

Install from ADB completed with status 2.
Installation aborted.

On the top of the phone, I also get
WARNING: Previous installation has failed.
  Your device may fail to boot if you reboot or power off now.

And Reboot to bootloader is highlighted. Should I be doing this?
The other options are
Reboot system now (unlikely this should be done given the above message)
Enter fastboot
Apply update from adb
Apply update from sdcard
Wipe data/factory reset
Mount /system
View recovery logs
Run graphics test
Run locale test
Power off

What should I be doing here? Would wipe data/factory reset resolve the issue?
I may note that I checked the sha256sum and it does match.
I can try sideloading again, but the device is no longer listed at this point.

Not sure about the 8a but older Pixel models had sometimes a downgrade protection, thus there was an not in the release not that if you install bootloader version x there is no way to downgrade later (without unlocking the bootloader). Thus I would recommend to check the release notes of all the versions after that 14 release you try to install. BTW please don't post links to firmware image in GDrive when all Pixel images are available as publishing c downloads on Google's web site.
